# How do I refresh the Android emulator network connection after the host switches network?

Tags: android, networking, android-emulator

I'm running an Android API 23 x86 emulator from SDK on my MacBook. When I switch WiFi network the Android emulator loses all connections to the internet or intranet.

Every time I switch my WiFi network I need to reboot my emulator to reset the network of the virtual Android device.

Is there an option to reinitialise the network connection of the emulator without rebooting?

Comment: I am using emulators on a mac as well didnt face this issue... are u using the latest emulators..maybe an update could solve this issue...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set on/off AirPlane mode from the command line:

```
adb shell settings put global airplane_mode_on 1 && adb shell settings put global airplane_mode_on 0
```

**Note** - also try this from ADB shell (Depends on your pc tcp drivers):

```
settings put global airplane_mode_on 1 && am broadcast -a android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE --ez state true && settings put global airplane_mode_on 0 && am broadcast -a android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE --ez state false
```

By doing so you re-initialize `TelephonyManager` and refresh the device modem drivers.